# PHP URL Rewrite not Working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried this code snippet for URL rewrite and it is not working.

Comment: Maybe mod rewrite is not installed? The snippet looks fine. Or your problem is because of trailing slashes? You might insert this line too: RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

According to me your **public/.htaccess** file should be like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Also please check that you've enabled mod rewrite in your apache via editing **php.ini** & **httpd.conf** file.

You can also follow these steps ([Link](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/#ssu)) to make your mod_rewrite URLs work

Don't forget to restart the Apache Service after doing this.

```
sudo apachectl restart // For MacOS
sudo service apache2 restart // For Ubuntu
```